# Pass array from AppDelegate to view controller

Tags: arrays, swift, appdelegate

I'm loading an array with data from a Firebase database in my AppDelegate as I need the arrays loaded before the views are created and loaded. How can I pass this array to a view controller to populate a TableView?

**Edit:**
I don't think I worded my question correctly nor provided enough information. I have this Firebase data that I need to load into an array. This array needs to be loaded into the app before it is used by the view controller that uses the array. This is because the view controller uses a cocoa pod that splits the array into a number of categories to be displayed in different tableviews. The repo for the cocoa pod I'm using can be found [here](https://github.com/azurechen/ACTabScrollView).

My question then is where is the best place to load this array? My first thought was the AppDelegate, but the array is empty and as such the table view doesn't load. I'm pretty new to iOS programming so I'm open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Why not load the data from the root view controller?

Comment: Consider that `applicationWillFinishLaunching` can be called later than `viewDidLoad` of the primary view controller 

Answer (score 0):

In the `AppDelegate` class:

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    //Fill your array, let's say it's called firebaseArray. I would recommend doing so in the view controller and not in the Appdelegate for better responsibility distribution in your code
    let vc = YourViewController()
    //And YourViewController must have a array property
    vc.array = firebaseArray
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    //make your vc the root view view controller
    window?.rootViewController = vc
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```